# React — Is this a good use of useCallback hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind what seems to be a new trend of defining all callbacks and/or event handlers with the `useCallback` hook.

As far as I understand it `onClick === Callback_A` is true as long as `x` remains the same:

```js
const onClick = useCallback(() => 42, [x]);
//                          ^^^^^^^^
//                          Callback_A
```

However the function expression (the 1st argument of `useCallback`) will always be a new one after each render. It is only discarded if `x` hasn't changed.

Suppose a component renders three times for some reason but `x` remains the same throughout:

```js
/*********************************** 1st render ***/

const onClick = useCallback(() => 42, [x]);
//    ^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
//    Callback_A            Callback_A

/*********************************** 2nd render ***/

const onClick = useCallback(() => 42, [x]);
//    ^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
//    Callback_A            Callback_A'

/*********************************** 3rd render ***/

const onClick = useCallback(() => 42, [x]);
//    ^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
//    Callback_A            Callback_A''
```

**If a new function expression (i.e. `() => 42`) is created upon each render regardless of `x` being the same or not why not simply assign it to `onClick` directly?**

When I make that observation during code reviews the answer is always a variant of *"it-is-to-avoid-useless-re-rendering-of-child-components"*.

I wanted to put this theory to the test and created a simple app with five buttons:
*(See screencast below)*

- Each button is associated with its own single state.
- The app re-renders every two seconds to update the value of just one button.
- All other buttons remain the same at all time
- Each button is given its own "onclick" handler.
- Each "onclick" handler is "generated" in a different way (e.g. with `useCallback` or not)

I count how many times onclick handlers are generated and how many onclick handlers each button actually uses:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const stats =
  { N: {}
  , B: {}
  , C: {}
  , D: {}
  , E: {} };

const register_handler = btn => {
  const now = performance.now();
  stats[btn][now] = false;
  return () => stats[btn][now] = true;
};

const print_stats = () => {
  console.table(
    Object.entries(stats).map(([button, handlers]) => ({
      button,
      count_generated: Object.keys(handlers).length,
      count_executed: Object.values(handlers).filter(b => b).length
    }))
  );
};

const e_click = register_handler('E');

export default function App() {
  // Only `n` will change. All other vars will remain the same.
  const [n, write_n] = useState(1);
  const [b] = useState('B');
  const [c] = useState('C');
  const [d] = useState('D');
  const [e] = useState('E');

  // Forces <App/> to re-render every two seconds.
  useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => write_n(n + 1), 2000));

  const n_click = useCallback(register_handler('N'), [n]);
  const b_click = useCallback(register_handler('B'), [b]);
  const c_click = register_handler('C');
  
  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>your buttons are belong to us</legend>
      <button value={n} onClick={n_click}>{n}</button>
      <button value={b} onClick={b_click}>{b}</button>
      <button value={c} onClick={c_click}>{c}</button>
      <button value={d} onClick={register_handler('D')}>{d}</button>
      <button value={e} onClick={e_click}>{e}</button>
      <hr />
      <button onClick={print_stats}>print stats</button>
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

I click on each button exactly **three times** then print some stats:

| Button | Number of handlers generated | Number of handlers used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | 24 | 3 |
| B | 24 | 1 |
| C | 24 | 3 |
| D | 24 | 3 |
| E | 1 | 1 |

Observations:

1. Except for button `E` all other buttons have generated way too many event handlers.
2. Both button `C` and `D` didn't use `useCallback` yet they didn't re-render.

Except for button `E` all other buttons have generated the same amount of event handlers but consumed only a few. Some have reused the same event handler throughout whilst others have used a new one each time. **How confident are we that the benefit of caching with `useCallback` outweights the cost of it?** I suppose that anything involving a cache comes with some trade-offs.

This unconditional love for `useCallback` also comes with some non-trivial maintenance cost. Not everybody is familiar with it and I suspect that some usage of it is driven by some degree of cargo cult programming.

**In this particular example, would anyone be justified to use `useCallback` and why?**

---

https://codesandbox.io/s/experimenting-with-usecallback-c4jf1

[image]

Comment: Starting with "I'm trying to understand the rationale behind what seems to be a new trend of defining all callbacks and/or event handlers with the useCallback hook.", How is it a trend? https://royi-codes.vercel.app/thousand-usecallbacks/, sounds like premature optimization, it surely shouldn't be overused

Comment: `useCallback` is just another form of memoization, of which there are tons of warnings out there about overusing. Overuse is a beginner mistake, and the common argument against extra-rerenders shows that they don't truly understand the performance implications of the code they're writing. In short, I think you're right that this isn't justified.